# Call a method in a CORE Razor Page from a ViewModel

Tags: razor-pages

My Razor Page

```
   public class IndexModel : BaseModel {
        public void OnGet() {
            BaseModelMethod();
        }
        public void LocalMethod() {}
   }
```

calls a method in the base ViewModel

```
public class BaseModel : PageModel {
    public void BaseModelMethod() {
        // Do stuff 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to call back to the instance of `LocalMethod` in the calling Razor Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the function as a virtual function. Your BaseModel has to have the following form:

```
public class BaseModel : PageModel
{
    public void BaseModelMethod()
    {
        LocalMethod();
    }

    public virtual void LocalMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see I creted the virtual function so that we will know what we kind of method we will call.

Now we can define our own version of LocalMethod like this:

```
public class IndexModel : BaseModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        BaseModelMethod();
    }

    public override void LocalMethod()
    {
        base.LocalMethod();
    }
}
```